# Как создать таблицу Excel с помощью Бота ВКонтакте?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, excel, api, бот

у меня стоит бот вконтакте на longpool, мне нужно сделать так чтобы он в определенной беседе (с помощью peer_id) выписывал Имена и Фамилию в таблицу Excel и рядом табличку с значениями цифр(3 бальная система). Можете подсказать идеи или (пожалуйста:) ) пример кода. Буду очень благодарен! Язык Python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для получения `id` всех участников беседы можно воспользоваться методом [`messages.getConversationMembers`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversationMembers).
Для получения их имён — [`users.get`](https://vk.com/dev/users.get).

Создание таблицы `xlsx` я доверил модулю [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from openpyxl import Workbook


ACCESS_TOKEN = '...'
PEER_ID = ...

def get_conversation_members_names(vk, peer_id: int) -> list:
    conversation_members = vk.messages.getConversationMembers(peer_id=peer_id)['items']
    members_ids = [str(member['member_id']) for member in conversation_members]

    users = vk.users.get(user_ids=','.join(members_ids))
    user_names = [' '.join((user['last_name'], user['first_name'])) for user in users]
    return user_names


def main() -> None:
    vkBotSession = VkApi(token=ACCESS_TOKEN)
    vk = vkBotSession.get_api()

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    names = get_conversation_members_names(vk, PEER_ID)

    lenght = len(names)
    for i, cell in enumerate(ws['A1':f'A{lenght}']):
        cell[0].value = names[i]

    wb.save('result.xlsx')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```